# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'No se puede encontrar la tabla 0.'

Tags: visual-studio, laragon, heidisql

estoy trabajando en un punto de venta en visual studio 2022, al momento de enlazar mi base de datos y al intentar depurar el proyecto, me salen estos errores, alguien me puede ayudar??? soy estudiante y les agradeceria mucho. estoy trabajandso con laragon y heidisql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]